# C# how to keep Checkbox checked of DataGridView when reload DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, datagridview

My application contains DataGridView with Checkbox added inside. How can I keep Checkbox checked when perform search and return new result in DataGridView.

```
    //List<DataGridViewRow> lst;
    List<string> lst;
    THEGATESEntities ge = new THEGATESEntities();
    DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn checkboxColSelect;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lst = new List<string>();
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in gridviewStaffs.Rows)
        {
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[checkboxColSelect.Name].Value) == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(row.Cells[2].Value.ToString());
                lst.Add(row.Cells[2].Value.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    private void txtName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var rs = from x in ge.Staffs
                 where x.username.Trim().ToLower().Contains(txtName.Text.Trim().ToLower())
                 select x;
        gridviewStaffs.DataSource = rs.ToList();

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in gridviewStaffs.Rows)
        {
            foreach (string uname in lst)
            {
                if (Convert.ToString(row.Cells[2].Value) == uname)
                {
                    row.Cells[checkboxColSelect.Name].Value = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should tag this Winforms as well if that is what you are using (I'm assuming this is the case since you are using DataGridView) so that way your question will reach the right people to help you. Click [edit] to edit your posts (also located below your question's tags) to add or remove tags

Comment: Thank you @GordonAllocman :) I forgot winforms tag

Comment: No problem, I would have added it myself but I wasn't 100% sure that was the case

Comment: In ge.Staffs, is Staffs a collection object of your own? What object type are you storing in this collection?

Comment: @BharatGupta Hi, I using Entity Framework, ge.Staffs is class of EF.